# Parsing txt file by date into 366 txt files

Tags: python, for-loop, parsing

I'm currently figuring out how to parse a text file into 366 separate files i.e Jan-1st.txt - Dec-30th.txt (one for every day of a leap year) and put the according date in that txt file. However i'm only new enough to python so I've become stuck. I initially started out by generating the files for January but I'd like to do this for all months in one script. This is my code so far. **Any help/tips would be brilliant!**

```
import re


for month in Months:
    book = open("BookToParse.txt", "r")
    book = str(book.read())
    month = re.split(month, book, flags = re.IGNORECASE)
    month.pop(0)

for i in range(0, len(month)+1)
    writeBook = open("{}-Jan.txt".format(i), "w+")
    writeBook.write(month[i-1])
    writeBook.close()
```

I'll insert a snippet from the book in question below

```
March 24th

  bla bla bla sometext here



March 25th

  Bla bla bla somemore text here


March 26th

 more text here...
```

Finally the parsed files should look like this; (cat Mar-25th.txt) I'm not overly picky about the naming convention of the parsed files once they are sequential.

```
March 25th

Bla Bla Bla
```

I know this is relatively easy to achieve which is why i'm reaching out to this community.**Thank you in advance for giving time to this and I look forward to your replies, A steer in the right direction would be greatly welcomed.**

Comment: Every time you encounter a new date, save the month and the day inside some variable. Then all you have to do is write the text you get in the file {day}_{month}.txt, until you find a new date, then you create another file and so on. If this is not clear enough, advise me and I'll come up with a more complete explanation.

Comment: Hey Allan, can you go into a bit more detail if possible? Just so I can breakdown the code I need to write, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working code. Explanation is in the commented lines.

```
months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
current_month = ""
current_date = ""

with open("BookToParse.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip().split(" ")[0] in months: # Just extracting the month
            # Benefit of extracting the month and date makes it easier for file handling
            current_month = line.strip().split(' ')[0]
            current_date = line.strip().split(' ')[1]

        g = open(current_month + '-' + current_date + '.txt', "a+") # Opening the file in append mode, handles if the file does not exist or there are multiple lines for the date
        if line.strip().split(" ")[0] not in months: # We do not need the lines containing date. 
            g.write(line)
        g.close()
```

#### Output

```
$ cat March-24th.txt

  bla bla bla sometext here



$ cat March-25th.txt

  Bla bla bla somemore text here


$ cat March-26th.txt

 more text here...


 some more text here...
 Harry


$ cat  April-29th.txt

  Ding Ding Ding

$ cat  June-3rd.txt
   Avada KaDavra

$ cat January-1st.txt
   Happy New Year
```

Comment: Plus, the way the dates and filenames are handled, it doesn't matter how many unique dates are there (365/ 366 its all the same).

Comment: Thank you so much! this was exactly what I was trying to figure out.

Comment: After playing around with next part of my project is there simple way I can rename the full month to '%m' + '%d' + '.txt' (i.e May-5th to 05-05)

Comment: Simplest would be to use index of the month. Just change the file open line as below.
`g = open(str(months.index(current_month)+1) + '-' + current_date[:-2] + '.txt', "a+")`

Comment: When I replace the original `g = open(current_month + '-' + current_date + '.txt', "a+")`with the above I get the following error: `ValueError: '' is not in list`

Comment: What is the format of dates in Bookstoparse.txt ? Is it consistent throughout (including case)?